# JSLink set in list definition (schema.xml) not being loaded

Tags: list-view, splist, jslink, spview

I have created a custom list definition and detailed in many articles across the net I have specified my file in the JSLink property of the view.  For some reason it is no longer working.

```
<JSLink Default="TRUE">/_layouts/15/myfile.js</JSLink>
```

Note: I have also tried ~layouts.
But for some reason when I create the list it is no longer working.
I have tried creating the list in both Powershell and the UI.

When I set the JSLink property on the web part on the view, it works as expected, but no through the schema.xml any more.

The javascript is trivial, basically just formatting a date not to show the time.  Which is irrespective because the file isn't loaded.  I've put a `console.log("")` message inside the file, which is only called when I set the JSLink property on the web part itself.
I can also see from View Source that the file is not being added.

I have checked the JSLink property on the View in Powershell and it is set to the one I define in the schema.xml

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you got a solution for this? I'm also getting the same issue. Could you please share if you have got it worked ?

Answer (score 6):

If the javascript file is located directly in the [layouts](/questions/tagged/layouts) folder you don't have to specify relative/full path as SharePoint will figure it out itself.

If you however have it located in a specific folder in either a document library or a in layouts, only then are you required to add a relative/full path to the javascript file.

Example:

(Located in layouts)

```
<JSLink>MyCustomJSFile.js</JSLink>
```

(Located in a folder)

```
// Located in subfolder in Layouts
<JSLink>~layouts/MyJSFiles/MyCustomJSFile.js</JSLink>
// Located in subfolder in Style Library on root
<JSLink>~sitecollection/Style Library/MyJSFiles/MyCustomJSFile.js</JSLink>
// Located in subfolder in Assets
<JSLink>~site/SiteAssets/MyJSFiles/MyCustomJSFile.js</JSLink>
```

Example with multiple javascript files

(Located in layouts)

```
// OOB SharePoint uses this method as well
<JSLink>MyFirstCustomJSFile.js|MySecondCustomJSFile.js</JSLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use one of the tokens

- ~site
- ~sitecollection
- ~layouts
- ~siteLayouts
- ~siteCollectionLayouts

I faced with problem that JSLink does not work without them.

**Edited**

In some cases you should encode "~" symbol.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, as stated, I've tried the ~layouts token.  No joy.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me, as I deployed solution using Visual Studio,

```
 <JSLink Default="TRUE">../_layouts/15/myFeaturesFolder.Features/myJSLINKFILE.js</JSLink>
```