# Accessing a js file from SitePage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm creating a sitepage from visual studio, which contains an xsltlistviewwebpart. I have created a new view using a JSLink script file. But, I'm not able to refer the same from the site page. I have given the path as

`<JSLink Default="TRUE">MyProjectName/JSLinkFAQ.js</JSLink>`

This is not working for me. I have added the JSLinkFAQ.js file in the layouts folder too.
What is the correct path to refer the file from a SitePages folder ?

EDIT

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly">
                    <ZoneTemplate>
                        <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8" Title="CreateFAQ" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" ListUrl="/Lists/FAQList" Default="FALSE" DisplayName="CreateFAQ" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" PartOrder="2" __WebPartId="{825496E8-4C44-4A1A-8ADC-D8641BBBC262}" ID="g_825496e8_4c44_4a1a_8adc_d8641bbbc262" ViewContentTypeId="0x" __designer:customxsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl">
                            <XmlDefinition>
                        <View Name="{5222A153-90CF-479D-9E99-27625D99638A}" Type="HTML" DisplayName="FAQ Home" Level="1" BaseViewID="2" ContentTypeID="0x">
                            <Query/>
                            <ViewFields>
                                <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
                                <FieldRef Name="FAQCategory"/>
                                <FieldRef Name="FAQDepartment"/>
                                <FieldRef Name="Author"/>
                                <FieldRef Name="Created"/>
                                <FieldRef Name="FAQQuestions"/>
                                <FieldRef Name="FAQStatus"/>
                            </ViewFields>
                            <RowLimit>2</RowLimit>
                            <JSLink Default="TRUE">/_layouts/15/SPDP.Portal.FAQ/JSLinkFAQ.js</JSLink>
                            <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
                            <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
                        </View>
                            </XmlDefinition>
                            <ParameterBindings>
                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                        <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(core,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
                        <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)" />
                            </ParameterBindings>
                        </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
                    </ZoneTemplate>
                </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

EDIT 2

Now, JSLink is working if I preview the page from the designer. But, if I go to visual studio and deploy the same page, its missing the JSLink!!!

Comment: You need to open your browser's debugging tools, figure out where the page is trying to load the file from, and adjust your JSLink value accordingly.

Comment: I have added it in many locations, still no luck. Its not loading the file. Designer preview works until we publish the same using visual studio. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to append /_layouts/15 in the file path. For example:

```
/_layouts/15/MyProjectName/JSLinkFAQ.js
```

**UPDATE**

I don't see any issue with the XML code you provided. You may try following:

- Use site relative path like ~site/AiteAssets/Filename.js. in the XML file.
- If the issue persists, try manually opening the XSLTListViewWebpart and adding file reference there using the site relative path.
- If you still face error then you may need to check whether your .js file is correct (free of errors) or not. This can be done by testing it on some other page rather than site page which you think is causing the problem.

Comment: I have given like this in the view, but still its not rendering. :( Any problem in rendering this from a site page ?

Comment: Can you hare full code?s

Comment: I have tried to add full webpart here, but unable to post.. How to format it to add with the question ?

Comment: @AnishV, Paste the code in, mark it and click the "{" icon in the RTE tools

Comment: Thanks @RobertLindgren. I have updated my question with code.

Comment: @AnishV, see my updated answer.

Comment: How to open that webpart manually ? You mean to take the properties window? I can't find a property for JSLink in that.

Comment: Click on Settings at the top and then click on Edit Page.
Then Select the web part representing the list. At the top right click on Edit Web Part.
Go to Miscellaneous section and you will find JSLink property.

Comment: Its working if I preview it from the designer. But, if I deploy it via Visual Studio, its not. :(

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [another similar post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/79631/8642), I would try to use the path `~layouts/SPDP.Portal.FAQ/JSLinkFAQ.js`, provided that your folder inside the layouts folder is actually named SPDP.Portal.FAQ

Comment: Its not working for me. :(

Comment: By "not working" do you mean that the file is not loaded at all?

Comment: Yes. Its not loading. Its working if I preview it from the designer. But, if I deploy it via Visual Studio, its not.

Comment: @AnishV Did you manually put your JS file into the layouts folder or do you deploy it via a Module in your feature?